# Flutter & firebase : The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am working on a application with flutter and firebase and i am working on the auth for user and i want tu use the function `uid` but it's dont work, why ?

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class FirebaseHelper {

//Authentification
final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<UserCredential> handleSignIn(String mail, String password) async{
 final UserCredential user = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: mail, password: password);
 return user;
}

Future<UserCredential> handleCreate(String mail, String password, String prenom, String nom) async{
 final UserCredential user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: mail, password: password);
 String uid = user.uid;
 Map<String, String> map = {
   "prenom" : prenom,
   "nom" : nom,
 };
 addUser(uid, map);
 return user;
}

//database

static final base = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
final base_user = base.child("users");

addUser(String id, Map map){
 base_user.child(uid).set(map);
}

}
```

it's mark `The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'.` and `Undefined name 'uid'.` I dont know what I can do... please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this, I find it really helpful to keep the reference documentation for  handy. In there, you can see that [`UserCredential`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html) indeed does not have a `uid` property, which explains the error message. If we browser a bit further, you'll notice that a credentials has a `user` property, which in turn has a `uid`.

So

```
 final UserCredential credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: mail, password: password);
 String uid = credential.user.uid; // or credential.user?.uid if you're using null-safety
```

Comment: thanks it's work fine for this but i use final ```UserCredential credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: mail, password: password);
    String uid = credential.user!.uid;``` and now it's work fine but it's say to me ```Undefined name 'uid'.``` at line 33 (here : ```addUser(String id, Map map){
 base_user.child(uid).set(map);```)
}

Comment: Oops, the `?` or `!` indeed needs to be after `user`. If that solves the original problem, then the new error is a new problem so I recommend posting a new question with the updated code and error message.

Comment: i can't post before 90min but do it, thank